# Union of more than $2$ subgroups can be a subgroup for some group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Actual Question  is :

> Suppose $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H\cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Prove that either $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$

I could do this just by assuming that I have  $h\in H; h\notin K$ and $k\in K; k\notin H$ then I would definitely have $hk\in H\cup K$ so $hk$ would be in either $H$ aor $K$ in any case it makes a contradiction.

Now the very next Question is :

> Show that for each integer $n\geq 3$ there exists a group $G$ with subgroups $H_1,H_2,\cdots,H_n$ such that no $H_i$ is contained in any other and such that $H_1\cup H_2\cup \cdots \cup H_n$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I guess we have to construct some group for given $n\geq 3$

For some reason for $n=3$ I have the following idea :

$n=3$ so there would be three subgroups and no subgroup is contained in any other..

Each subgroup must have atleast $1$ non identity element so there are $3$ non identity elements adding up identity element i would get $4$ elements.

It would be extra ordinary if my choice of group is just of $4$ elements.

It would not be a wise choice if i choose my group to be cyclic so only choice i have is  $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z_2}=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$

Each element is of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z_2}$ is of order $2$ so I would just take $H_1=\{(0,0),(1,0)\};H_2=\{(0,0),(0,1)\};H_3=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$

So, I have $H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3$ to be whole group (which is More than sufficient)... I just need it to be a subgroup and it has become the whole group..

Now I got a group in which union of $3$ subgroups is a subgroup..

I have  one more example for the case of $n=3$ - Quaternion Group

$H_1=\{\pm 1,\pm i\}; H_2=\{\pm 1,\pm j\};H_3=\{\pm 1,\pm ij\}$

Here also I have $H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3=\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm ij\}$ Which is a subgroup of $G$ and more over it is the whole group.

Now I have got another Question :

Is this just by chance that union of three proper subgroups is whole group of there are some examples in which union of three proper subgroups is a proper subgroup... I could not see this immediately

I really have no idea how to go with $n=4$ and so on...

Please help me to see some way with this problem...

Thank you.

Comment: If you take your examples of subgroups with union a group $G$, and choose another group $K$, all will be proper subgroups of $G \times K.$

Comment: @coffeemath : Yes Yes.. That does makes sense to me... I do not know what to say

Comment: So to do it for any $n$, use coffeemath's example $G \times K$ for some group $K$ with lots of subgroups. Then $G \times K$ is a union of three proper subgroups, and for the other subgroups, you can just choose $G \times L$ for lots of different subgroups $L$ of $K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I do not really understand the idea behind coffeemath's statement and I do not understand your idea too... Could you please rephrase or explain a a bit more..

Comment: WeiZhou has answered the question now.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I do not understand it either.. :O

Comment: He has written down $k+1$ subgroup with union $G \times G$. What is there not to understand? This problem would be more difficult if you specified that the union should not be redundant. As it stands, we  just find a union of $k$ subgroups equal to $G$, and then we c an throw in any other subgroups we like!

Comment: This is more difficult. I have no clue.

Answer (score 4):

Derek Holt and Wei Zhou answered the question:

> Show that for each integer $n\geq 3$ there exists a group $G$ with subgroups $H_1,H_2,\cdots,H_n$ such that no $H_i$ is contained in any other and such that $H_1\cup H_2\cup \cdots \cup H_n = G$.

(The original question specifies the union be a subgroup, but there is no loss in taking $G$ itself to be that subgroup.)

The idea is to take some smaller group $K$ that is the union of $n-1$ subgroups $K_1$, $K_2$, $\dots$, $K_{n-1}$, and then form $G=K \times L$ for some non-identity group $L$. Take $H_1=K_1 \times L$, $H_2=K_2 \times L$, $\dots$, $H_{n-1} = K_{n-1} \times L$ and $H_n = K \times 1$. You can verify that $H_n \not\subset H_i$ (since $H_i$ does not contain *every* $(x,1)$ for $x \in K$) and $H_i \not\subset H_n$ (since $H_n$ does not contain $(1,x)$ for any $1\neq x \in L$).

However, Praphulla Koushik was understandably confused since $G$ was also the union $H_1 \cup \dots \cup H_{n-1}$, the last $H_n$ was redundant. I don't address the existence of non-redundant unions (or “coverings”) of size $n$, but I do address the **minimal size** of a covering:

> Let $\sigma(G)$ be the least $n$ such that $G$ is the union of $n$ proper subgroups.

Clearly $\sigma(C_n) = \infty$ but otherwise for a finite group $G$, $\sigma(G)$ is finite. The obvious generalization is:

> Show that for each integer $n$ there exists a group $G$ with $\sigma(G)=n$.

However, Cohn (1994) conjectured this was impossible for $n=7$, and Tomkinson (1997) proved this. Tomkinson also gave a formula for $\sigma(G)$ when $G$ is solvable: $\sigma(G)=[H:K]$ where $H/K$ is a the smallest chief factor with more than one complement.

We say that a group $G$ is $\sigma$-primitive if $G$ has no non-identity normal subgroup $N$ with $\sigma(G)=\sigma(G/N)$. In some sense, the $\sigma$-primitive groups are the only interesting ones (as the others just have $N \leq \cap H_i$ so the $N$ part could have been ignored).

As a standard exercise, $\sigma(G)\leq 2$ is impossible.

Cohn found the $\sigma$-primitive groups $G$ with $\sigma(G)=3$: only $C_2 \times C_2$, the same group Praphulla Koushik deduced. He also handled $\sigma(G)=4$: only $C_3\times C_3$ and $S_3$, and $\sigma(G)=5$: only $A_4$. Notice each of these is of the form $p^a+1$ for $p$ prime and $a$ positive. The first number $\geq 3$ not of this form is $7$, and it is not a $\sigma$-number. Current research involves studying the structure $\sigma$-primitive groups and finding $\sigma(G)$ for groups $G$ known to be $\sigma$-primitive. Detomi–Lucchini (2008) gives a good indication on the structure, and several papers compute $\sigma$ for (usually finitely many) simple groups.

### Bibliography

- Cohn, J. H. E.
  “[On $n$-sum groups.](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12501/10517)”
  Math. Scand. 75 (1994), no. 1, 44–58. 
  MR[1308936](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1308936)
- Tomkinson, M. J.
  “[Groups as the union of proper subgroups.](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12873/10888)”
  Math. Scand. 81 (1997), no. 2, 191–198.
  MR[1613772](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1613772)
- Detomi, Eloisa; Lucchini, Andrea.
  “[On the structure of primitive n-sum groups.](http://www.dmat.ufpe.br/CUBO/files/v10n3/CUBO_n3_2008/N16.pdf)”
  Cubo 10 (2008), no. 3, 195–210.
  MR[2467921](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2467921)

Comment: So I am still wondering whether for every $n\ge 3$ we can find a group that is a non-redundant union of $n$ subgroups. That's easy for $n=7$: the subgroups of order $2$ in an elementary group of order $8$.

Comment: Yes, I think non-redundant is an interesting question; I just didn't have any good answer. I've attended a few talks on $\sigma$, and so found it easy to write up this little bit (haven't had time to find links to online copies of the papers yet).

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130050/covering-of-a-group-by-seven-proper-subgroups-counterexample

Comment: I was sure you would understand my problem and you did... I could not understand why would you want to pick another subgroup (adding upto $n$ subgroups) when the group is already being covered by $n-1$ subgroups... Now it does makes sense to me... This problem is much harder than i thought it would be :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: On the contrary, the question you actually asked was easy, which seemed to be what was confusing you! There are some much more difficult related questions.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a "$k$"-example: $G=A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_k$, where $A_i <G$. Let $H$ be a group isomorphic to $G$, then there exists $B_1 \le H$ and $B_1 \cong A_1$. Now consider the group $X=G \times H$. Clearly $X=A_1 \times H\cup \cdots \cup A_k \times H$. Let $X_i=A_i \times H$. So $X=X_1 \cup \cdots X_k$. Let $X_{k+1}=G \times B_1$. Now you can find that $X, X_1, \cdots,  X_{k+1}$ is a "$k+1$"-example. So if $k$ is right, then $k+1$ is right.

Comment: I do not really get your idea behind choosing $A_{k+1}=G\times A_1$ :O

Comment: Maybe it is easy to understand if we write the two isomorphic direct factors in two different letters.

Comment: I have reedited it.

Comment: Why not use $H=G$ and $B_1=A_1$?

Comment: I am getting confused with the notation... Let me tell you what i have understood.... Suppose for $k\geq 3$ I have a group $G$ such that $G=H_1\cup H_2\cup \cdots \cup H_k$.. Now i have to find another group such that there are $k+1$ subgroups whose union is a subgroup...  Another reason i am getting confused is I was expecting union to be a subgroup (possibly proper) but it is actually whole group..

Comment: @Christoph My original answer use your notation. I change them to make it easily underestood.

Comment: @praphulla Yes, the answer is from a $k$-example ($G, A_1, \cdots, A_k$) to a $k+1$-example ($X, X_1, \cdots, X_{k+1}$. The other confusion is not necessary, for we can always embeded a group in a biger group. For example, you can consider $X \times <a>$ to get a "proper" case.

Comment: I would do it for My example of  $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$... I have $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z_2}=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}=H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3$ As you said i would consider $$G\times G = (H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3)\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)= (H_1\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2))\cup (H_2\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2))\cup(H_3\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2))=X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$$ For $X_i=(H_i\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2))$ for $i=1,2,3$.. Now what should be my next step?

Comment: Your choice of $X_4$ is $X_4=(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2))\times H_1$... This does not seem to be natural for me.... :O I am dumb... :(

Comment: If you write the direct product in external direct product, you will find $X_4 \ne X_1$. And $Xi$ is not a subgroup of $X_j$ if $i \ne j$. You get lost because you write group in isomorphic way.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand... May be i would think for some time.... Thank you for your interest :)

Answer (score 0):

As was noted, a group cannot be the union of two of its proper subgroups. It might be interesting to know, that research has been done on how this might generalize. Berci gave you an example based on the Klein 4-group. In fact more is true:

**Theorem** (Bruckheimer, Bryan and Muir) A group is the union of three proper subgroups if and only if it has a quotient isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$.

The proof appeared in the American Math. Monthly $77$, no. $1 (1970)$. The theorem seems to be proved earlier by the Italian mathematician Gaetano Scorza, *I gruppi che possono pensarsi come somma di tre loro sottogruppi*, Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. $5 (1926), 216-218$.

For 4, 5 or 6 subgroups a similar theorem is true and the Klein 4-group is for each of the cases replaced by some finite set of groups. For 7 subgroups however, it is not true: no group can be written as a union of 7 of its proper subgroups. This was proved by Tomkinson in 1997.

There is a nice overview paper by Mira Bhargava, *Groups as unions of subgroups*, The American Mathematical Monthly, $116$, no. $5, (2009)$.